# Re-merging two disk that used to mirror each other

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, raid, raid-1, disk-management

I have had two hard disks that mirrored each other (RAID 1, software based). After I recently plugged them out of the mother board and plugged them back in, this mirrored volume was unavailable.

I looked under Disk Management in Windows 8, and the status of both drives was "Failed". One of them was listed as a "Foreign disk". After going through a dialog for "Import foreign disks", I now have both drives listed and available in Explorer. Disk Management now looks like this:

[image: Disk Management]

E: and F: have the same contents, but do not mirror each other any more. How can I make them mirror each other, and show up as one drive in Explorer?

(I vaguely recollect that I had to somehow involve the BIOS when I set this up, don't know if that detail helps.)

Comment: You can right click one of the disks and click "Create mirror" (I Think... I'm not by my PC to check)... Windows can create a software RAID1... If you prefer to use your BIOS to create a RAID then you can use this instead, if you prefer.

Comment: There's an "Add mirror" option when I right click, but it's disabled. No "Create mirror" unfortunately. (I should mention that I need to keep the data on the drives intact)

Comment: That's the one ("Add mirror"). It will make a bit-by-bit copy of the disk you've highlighted. I've no doubt it will format the destination disk so, yes, one disk will be erased to "mirror" the other. If you need both disks to remain with their existing contents then you will need additional disks.

Comment: Are you using Intel Rapid Storage driver? I believe there should be some recovery options in that...

Comment: @BigChris Any idea how to enable that option? It's disabled when I right click.

Comment: @Vitas Don't think I'm using that atm. I'll look into it, see if it can help, thanks.

Comment: You may need to convert the disk to a dynamic disk before the option will be enabled. Backup your data beforehand! We offer advice but it is of utmost importance that you have a backup of your data before proceeding!

Comment: Hmm, the disk is already listed as dynamic. Some googling indicates that formatting the second disk will enable the "Add mirror" option. I'll wait with trying this until I've made a backup. If you want to submit this as a seperate answer Chris, I'll mark it as accepted.